# Kafka to Spark batch processing

Tags: apache-spark, redis, apache-kafka, hbase

I'm looking for an optimal data architecture.

I'm dealing with TS data that is flushed from a Redis database to OpenTSDB database each week. 
OpenTSDB stores its data on HBase which is launched on a Hadoop cluster.

Then, the time series data available on OpenTSDB has to be batch processed (at 1-6 months interval).
[image]

Knowing that OpenTSDB data is stored in Binary large object format on HBase, I can't currently tackle HBase HTTP API.

Since Spark cannot directly access OpenTSDB API (While Kafka seems to be Okay with HTTP Api)... I'm facing architecture issues which can be expressed as follows, would it be more convenient to:

- Use Apache Kafka to extract batch data (TByte) and use it as a pipeline to ingest and analyze data into Spark Dataframes ?
- Flush redis data directly in HBase and hence use Spark directly from it ?

That said, I want to be sure than Spark can handle terabytes batch analytics and kafka can handle that amount before loading it as Spark RDD.

Any suggestion on help will be welcome. Thanks

Comment: Too broad + opinion based. Please divide your question into smaller questions with no "best" in description, because recommendations are off topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Okay, here's a smaller question  :  Is Apache Kafka useful to extract Terabytes of data and be used as a pipeline to ingest it and batch process it into Spark Dataframes ?

Comment: @MehdiOua did you get a solution?